# UnityPython working on Editor but not on Build

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, ironpython

I am making a game wherein the player executes Python code in order to move the character. The way I've done this is with [UnityPython](https://github.com/exodrifter/unity-python), which is basically just IronPython integrated within Unity. The way this works is the code input from the player is wrapped inside a Python script. This script is then run on another thread (this is working from the wrapper, using Python's `threading` class) which communicates with Unity to move the player. This system works fine on the editor, but not on the build.

At first, I have pinpointed the problem to be coming from the search paths used by the script engine not locating the proper library folder (because UnityPython itself is within the assets folder). The particular classes that I need are `threading` and `Queue`.

The engine initializer looks like this:

```
var engine = UnityPython.CreateEngine();
var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
paths.Add(Application.dataPath + "/Python/Lib");
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
```

One workaround I've thought of is just copying the Python folder to the StreamingAssets folder, and then using `Application.streamingAssetsPath` on the third line instead. But the dev build debugger then gives me this weird error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'CodecsInfo' threw an exception. ---> System.NotSupportedException:
>   Encoding 37 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct
>   international codeset assembly installed and enabled.

This is where I am stuck at right now. Any thoughts on what this error means and how to go around it?

Edit: the problem seems to be happening when the script is used by the engine. The code here goes like this:

```
try
{
    var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(scriptPath);
    source.Compile();
    // script here is a dynamic variable
    script = engine.Runtime.UseFile(scriptPath); // this is where the error is thrown
    script.GameManager = this;
    script.start();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.Log("Error: " + e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by missing DLLs not being copied over the build from the editor. Credits to exodrifter for the solution (found [here](https://github.com/exodrifter/unity-python/issues/20#issuecomment-538683839)).

Simply put, these DLLs are required on the Plugins folder of the project.

- I18N.CJK.dll
- I18N.dll
- I18N.MidEast.dll
- I18N.Other.dll
- I18N.Rare.dll
- I18N.West.dll

They can be copied over from Unity Editor's install location. The DLLs are located at `Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0`. The exact location depends on where you installed Unity. In my case, it was at `C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.7f1\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0`